# I came across a proposed solution for the 4SUM problem which supposedly solves it in O(nlogn) time. Can somoene disprove it?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The time complexity for this seems to be O(nlogn) as we first sort the array and then perform a 4 pointer approach (which is linear in time complexity).

They use 4 pointers LL, LR, RR and RL where the sums of the 4 pointers are added and based on the most optimal movements, they choose to move the pointers accordingly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n = 8;
    int a[n] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8};
    int x = 16;
    sort(a, a + n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << ",";
    }
    cout << endl;
    int LL = 0;
    int LR = 1;
    int RL = n - 2;
    int RR = n - 1;
    //cout << LL << "," << LR << "," << RL << "," << RR << endl;
    while (LR < RL)
    {
        if ((a[LL] + a[LR] + a[RL] + a[RR]) > x)
        {
            //cout << (a[LL] + a[LR] + a[RR] + a[RR]) << endl;
            if (a[RL] - a[RL - 1] < ((a[RR] + a[RL]) - (a[RL] + a[RL - 1])))
            {
                RL--;
            }
            else
            {
                RL--;
                RR--;
            }
        }
        else if ((a[LL] + a[LR] + a[RL] + a[RR]) < x)
        {

            if (a[LR + 1] - a[LR] < ((a[LR + 1] + a[LR]) - (a[LL] + a[LR])))
            {
                LR++;
            }
            else
            {
                LL++;
                LR++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The four elements are:" << a[LL] << "," << a[LR] << "," << a[RL] << "," << a[RR];
            return 0;
        }
        //cout << LL << "," << LR << "," << RL << "," << RR << endl;
    }
    cout << "No such four elements exists";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you actually explain your logic behind the _"optimum pointer movement"_

Comment: Try the array presented, `x`=10 or 26. Try to find *any* input where there are values reported that does not include minimum as well as maximum. The inequalities controlling movement of RR&LL can greatly be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I could take this (any, at that) solution to 4SUM, add a zero to the multiset and use it to solve [3SUM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM).

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is O(nlogn) but it doesn't do what you think. Your 4SUM algorithm works mostly but here is a counterexample.

First of all let me simplify the "if" and "else if" statements of your 4SUM logic. Here's an equivalent:

```
if ((a[LL] + a[LR] + a[RL] + a[RR]) > x)
{
    if (a[RL] < a[RR])
    {
        RL--;
    }
    else
    {
        RL--;
        RR--;
    }
}
else if ((a[LL] + a[LR] + a[RL] + a[RR]) < x)
{

    if (  a[LR] >  a[LL])
    {
        LR++;
    }
    else
    {
        LL++;
        LR++;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "The four elements are:" << a[LL] << "," << a[LR] << "," << a[RL] << "," << a[RR];
    return 0;
}
```

Here a counter example:
Ordered array: 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7
Goal sum: 14

**Iteration 1:**
LL = 1, LR = 2, RL = 6 and RR = 7
16 > 14 and RL < RR then RL--

**Iteration 2:**
LL = 1, LR = 2, RL = 5 and RR = 7
15 > 14 and RL < RR then RL--

**Iteration 3:**
LL = 1, LR = 2, RL = 3 and RR = 7
13 < 14 and LR > LL then LR++

**Iteration 4:**
LL = 1, LR = 3, RL = 3 and RR = 7
Invalid, using twice the same number